# I am having a problem with the base64_decode output in Perl being truncated

Tags: perl, base64, key, decode

I am attempting to base64_decode a key that was initially base64 encoded by another program.  I am not getting back to the original value which is causing my program to fail.  Could someone help me to understand what I am doing incorrectly?

The original key is stored in the file key_e.bin:

hexdump key_e.bin
0000000 8e48 7360 9641 3c4a a2ed d804 2525 c629
0000010 28e2 cb6d 0f60 5a73 b8b0 f7c2 f98b cfaf
0000020 2780 bbea 3860 0a90
0000028

When I use the bash prompt version of base64 it works fine.

> base64 -w0 key_e.bin > key_e.b64
> cat key_e.b64
> SI5gc0GWSjztogTYJSUpxuIobctgD3NasLjC94v5r8+AJ+q7YDiQCg==
> base64 -d -w0 key_e.b64 > resultant_key_e.bin
> hexdump resultant_key_e.bin
> 0000000 8e48 7360 9641 3c4a a2ed d804 2525 c629
> 0000010 28e2 cb6d 0f60 5a73 b8b0 f7c2 f98b cfaf
> 0000020 2780 bbea 3860 0a90
> 0000028

In perl, I do not get this same result.
My code:

```
open IN, '<', "key_e.bin" or die "Can't read key_e.bin file $!";
my $key_e_from_file = <IN>;
close IN;

my $key_e_b64 = encode_base64($key_e_from_file);
print "The base64 encoded key e is:\n\t$key_e_b64\n";

# Now attempt to base64 decode this value
my $key_e_bin = decode_base64($key_e_b64);
open OUT, '>', "key_e_from_perl.bin" or die "Can't write to output file $!";
binmode OUT;
print OUT "key_e_bin";
close OUT;
```

Back at the bash prompt, I see the b64 version as the same value as before:
SI5gc0GWSjztogTYJSUpxuIobctgD3NasLjC94v5r8+AJ+q7YDiQCg==
However, the bin file contains incorrect data:

> hexdump key_e_from_perl.bin
> 0000000 8e48 7360 9641 3c4a a2ed d804 2525 c629
> 0000010 28e2 cb6d 0f60 5a73 b8b0 f7c2 f98b cfaf
> 0000020 2780 bbea 3860 0090
> 0000028

Note that byte 0x26 is 00, not 0a.

Comment: Among other problems, you treat the binary file as a text file and only read the first line's worth (i..e you ignore all the content in the binary file after the first \n).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted just writes the name of the variable `key_e_bin` instead of its value to the file `key_e_from_perl.bin`. If indeed the value is printed, the outcome is correct, provided that a missing `use MIME::Base64;` is prepended to the code. The described data with only *byte 0x26* (actually byte 0x27, since the word's MSB comes second) incorrect must come from a quite different program.